# Is there a way to disable or enable text wrapping in cells?

Tags: front-end, cells

I am trying to generate `"Program"` cells but my issue is unlike `"Code"` cells, `"Program"` cells automatically start text wrapping when the line is too long for the screen. Is there an option or something to make these `"Program"` cells not have text wrapping so very long lines of code can go off-screen but remain in the same line like `"Code"` cells.

Here is an example `"Program"` cell:

```
long=StringJoin@Table[".",1000];
CellPrint@Cell[TextData[{
    StyleBox["Code:",FontWeight->"Bold"],"   ",
    " ... very long piece of code "<>long,"\n",
    StyleBox["Comment:",FontWeight->"Bold"],
    " ... very long comment ......"<>long
}], "Program"]
```

Here is an example `"Code"` cell:

```
CellPrint@Cell[TextData[{
    StyleBox["Code:",FontWeight->"Bold"],"   ",
    " ... very long piece of code "<>long,"\n",
    StyleBox["Comment:",FontWeight->"Bold"],
    " ... very long comment ......"<>long
}], "Code"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works for you

```
long = StringJoin@Table[".", 1000];
CellPrint[
 Cell[TextData[{StyleBox["Code:", FontWeight -> "Bold"], "   ", 
    " ... very long piece of code " <> long, "\n", 
    StyleBox["Comment:", FontWeight -> "Bold"], 
    " ... very long comment ......" <> long}], "Program", 
  "PageWidth" -> Infinity]]
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! Weird I can't find this option in the `Cell` reference page but it is mentioned on the `PageWidth` reference page that it works with `Cell`.